# Bootstrap btn-group flex-wrap issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm having some trouble with a bootstrap form (using Bootstrap 4). I need my btn-group buttons to wrap when resizing. It works like a charm when adding flex-wrap BUT there's one problem : the bottom of my buttons are hidden.. And i can't understand why!
I've tried everything (adding padding all type of things) but i can't figure it out.
[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmGgQ.png)

And here is the code :

```
<div class="form-row">
  <div class="col-md-12 form-group mb-5 ">
    <label>Type de bien *</label><br />
    <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle flex-wrap" data-toggle="buttons">
      <label class="btn btn-qual btn-toggle active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> Maison
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-qual btn-toggle">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"> Appartement
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-qual btn-toggle">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Duplex
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-qual btn-toggle">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Triplex
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-qual btn-toggle">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Loft/Atelier
      </label>
      <label class="btn btn-qual btn-toggle">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> Hôtel Particulier
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone having an idea for how to fix this one?

Comment: Can you please add the required CSS in above code, so its easy to preview and debug.

Comment: Would help to know what CSS is being applied via `.btn-qual` as this is not a default Bootstrap style. Also why are you using `form-row` and `form-group` in this fashion? The use of a column seems unnecessary as well.

Comment: Hey so i'm using these classes because it's only a little part from a multistep form that is way longer! Here is the css for the .btn-qual elements : 
    `.btn-qual{
  border: 1px solid #DBDBDB;
}

.btn-qual:hover{
  border: 1px solid #ffd16d;
}

.btn-qual:active, .btn-qual.active, .btn-qual:focus{
  border: 1px solid #ffd16d;
  background: #FFF4D4;
}`